# Ibus anthy/mozc works in every program except for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ibus, japanese

I've installed both anthy and mozc in order to type Japanese characters on my system, and it works for the most part: Both work in Skype, LibreOffice, the Terminal, and everything else I have tried EXCEPT for Chrome, even Firefox. When I switch my input method to either it should type in Japanese in Chrome but instead it only types roman characters. If necessary I can type in a word-processor and copy and paste the Japanese text into Chrome but this is both annoying and impractical, and I don't actually like Firefox.

I have found lots of people with the same problem by googling it, and know that the same or a similar issue was asked on this website too, but in none of those places where it was mentioned was anyone able to provide a solution.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/389546/ibus-japanese-input-anthy-does-not-work-in-chrome-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: There is only one suggested solution there and it did not solve my problem.

Comment: that's why I didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

I found your question after Mozc mysteriously stopped working in Chrome in Mint XFCE 17.2. Funnily enough, I had *just* been using it earlier in the morning to type Japanese within Chrome.

The only thing that changed was that **I'd installed the `ibus-gtk3` package** while trying to troubleshoot the fact that Mozc's suggestion box would appear at the bottom of the Chrome window whenever I was typing.

As luck would have it, **uninstalling** `ibus-gtk3` solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus-gtk3
```

Once you log out and then log back in, Mozc should start working again in Chrome, though if your system is like mine then the popup appears in the bottom-left corner of the window instead of just under the cursor:

[image: The Mozc window appears in the bottom-left corner of the window]

Anyway, as you can see in the picture this re-enabled Mozc functionality within Chrome.

**EDIT:** I poked around a bit more and managed to re-fix this issue by opening up Mint's **Language Settings**, going to **Input Method**, and then clicking **Install Missing Components** next to the IBus option.

This added the following four packages:

```
ibus-clutter
ibus-gtk
ibus-gtk3
ibus-qt4
```

After restarting mdm:

```
sudo restart mdm
```

IBus came back up without issue, and I confirmed that Mozc works fine in Chrome. It even fixed the placement of the pop-up window that I was complaining about earlier!

Please keep in mind that I'm testing all of this out in Mint 17.2. I know this is ask**ubuntu**.com, but since the two are so similar hopefully there's enough info here to help you figure this out.

Comment: The "EDIT" was exactly what I needed.  I confirm this fix also works on Debian/KDE!